# How to Enable SSL/HTTPS on Tomcat 7 on RHEL

Tags: java, linux, ssl-certificate, redhat, rhel

I have a Java application which I am running on RHEL server. I want to enable SSL on tomcat 7 on RHEL. I am following [this tutorial](http://www.mkyong.com/tomcat/how-to-configure-tomcat-to-support-ssl-or-https/).

I used this command to to create a self-signed certificate.

```
keytool -genkey -alias mkyong -keyalg RSA -keystore c:\mkyongkeystore
```

But on running `https://localhost:8443/` I am not getting anything and I am enable to configure Tomcat to support SSL Or https.

Comment: Between "I want to enable SSL on tomcat 7 on RHEL(Red Hat)" and "-keystore c:\mkyongkeystore", I hardly see any sense..

Comment: @kagali-san my bad on explanation. I am running keytool command in tomcat lib directory

Comment: c:\mkyongkeystore is windows path, what was the exact command you've used on RHEL?

Comment: @kagali-san "keytool -genkey -alias mkyong -keyalg RSA -keystore c:\mkyongkeystore" I am running this command on the cmd prompt in the tomcat bin directory as described in the mkyong tutorial. I have provided the link for the same in my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A) Create a keystore file to store the server's private key and self-signed certificate by executing the following command:

keytool -genkey -alias tomcat -keyalg RSA -keystore /etc/tomcat6/keystore

B) Uncomment the "SSL HTTP/1.1 Connector" entry in /etc/tomcat6/server.xml and modify as described in the Configuration section below (this is only an example, edit your own configuration and just uncomment it and provide the correct password).

```
<!-- Define a SSL HTTP/1.1 Connector on port 8443
     This connector uses the JSSE configuration, when using APR, the
     connector should be using the OpenSSL style configuration
     described in the APR documentation -->

<Connector port="8443" protocol="HTTP/1.1" SSLEnabled="true"
           maxThreads="150" scheme="https" secure="true"
           clientAuth="want" SSLProtocol="TLS"
           keystoreFile="conf/keystore"
           truststoreFile="conf/keystore"
           keystorePass="XXXXXX"
           keystoreType="PKCS12"
           ciphers="SSL_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA,
                TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA,
                TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA,
                TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA,
                TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA,
                TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA,
                TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA,
                TLS_ECDH_anon_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA,
                TLS_ECDH_anon_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA,
                TLS_ECDH_anon_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA"
           truststorePass="XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX" />
```

C) If you are using selinux, you may need to relabel newly created keystore file context. Use RHEL SELinux guide how to do that.